# Retrieve an image from form to create record on airtable with request post fetch on React Native

Tags: react-native, image, fetch, form-data, airtable

I try to create a record on airtable via an API POST request but I have difficulties to retrieve image url.

When I choose an image from the form, I use the expo-image-picker to retrieve it and his url. Airtable ask to create an array of attachment objects for the "Photos" :

- To create new attachments in Photos, set the field value to an array of attachment objects. When creating an attachment, url is required, and filename is optional. Airtable will download the file at the given url and keep its own copy of it. All other attachment object properties will be generated server-side soon afterward. (API Documentation Airtable)*

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, SafeAreaView, Image, Text} from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import { REACT_APP_API_KEY, BASE_API } from '@env';

export default function Add() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
    const [level, setLevel] = useState(null)
    const [surfBreak, setSurfBreak] = useState('');
    const [peakSurfSeasonBegins, setPeakSurfSeasonBegins] = useState("");
    const [peakSurfSeasonEnds, setPeakSurfSeasonEnds] = useState("");
    const [influencers, setInfluencers] = useState("");
    const [geocode, setGeocode] = useState("");
    const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);
    const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState("");
    const formData = new FormData();
    const apiKey = REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    const apiEndpoint = BASE_API;

    const newData = {
        fields: {
            "Destination": location,
            "Destination State/Country": country,
            "Difficulty Level": Number(level),
            "Surf Break": [
              surfBreak
            ],
            "Photos": [
              {
                "url": imageUri
              }
            ],
            "Peak Surf Season Begins": peakSurfSeasonBegins,
            "Peak Surf Season Ends": peakSurfSeasonEnds,
            "Magic Seaweed Link": "https://magicseaweed.com/Pipeline-Backdoor-Surf-Report/616/",
            "Influencers": [
              influencers
            ],
            "Geocode": geocode
        }
    }

    const PostData = async () => {
        await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": apiKey,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newData)
        })
        .then(response =>  response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))

        /*setLocation("");
        setCountry("");
        setGeocode("");
        setName("");
        setLevel(null);
        setSurfBreak("");
        setImageUri(null);
        setInfluencers("");
        setPeakSurfSeasonBegins("");
        setPeakSurfSeasonEnds("");*/

    } 

    useEffect(() => {
        PostData();
    },[])

    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
        if(!result.canceled) {
            setImageUri(result.assets[0].uri);
            console.log(imageUri);
        }
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center"}}>
            <View style={style.inputs}>
                <TextInput 
                style={style.input} 
                onChangeText={setName}
                value={name}
                placeholder='Name'
                />
                <TextInput
                style={style.input}
                onChangeText={setLocation}
                value={location}
                placeholder='Location'
                />
                <TextInput 
                style={style.input} 
                onChangeText={setCountry}
                value={country}
                placeholder='Country'
                />
                <TextInput 
                style={style.input} 
                onChangeText={setLevel}
                value={level}
                placeholder='Level'
                />
                <TextInput
                style={style.input}
                onChangeText={setSurfBreak}
                value={surfBreak}
                placeholder='Surf Break'
                />
                <TextInput 
                style={style.input} 
                onChangeText={setPeakSurfSeasonBegins}
                value={peakSurfSeasonBegins}
                placeholder='Peak Surf Season Begins'
                />
                <TextInput
                style={style.input}
                onChangeText={setPeakSurfSeasonEnds}
                value={peakSurfSeasonEnds}
                placeholder='Peak Surf Season Ends'
                />
                <TextInput
                style={style.input}
                onChangeText={setInfluencers}
                value={influencers}
                placeholder='Influencers'
                />
                <TextInput
                style={style.input}
                onChangeText={setGeocode}
                value={geocode}
                placeholder='Geocode'
                />
                <Button title='Select an image' onPress={pickImage}/>
                {imageUri && 
                <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} 
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100, marginLeft: "auto", marginRight:"auto" }}
                />}
                <Button title='Submit' onPress={PostData}/>
                <Text style={style.text}>{confirm}</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: "grey",
        padding: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 60
    },
    inputs: {
        rowGap: 30
    },
    text: {
        marginRight: "auto",
        marginLeft:"auto"
    }
})
```

With a console.log I have the url :

```
 LOG  file:///Users/alfa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3E72F4D-C6A7-4D54-8005-06420EF6A447/data/Containers/Data/Application/465D8549-E98B-4FE8-B76B-52A892814D00/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fmobile_project-b3057085-ad6c-46a0-a061-03bc5040064c/ImagePicker/A5CD2BBF-DB59-4DFE-BE7B-44624AB5B255.jpg
```

When I validate the form with all filled fields. I have object with all fields :

```
 {"createdTime": "2023-05-18T18:22:53.000Z", "fields": {"Address": "St Marie de Ré, France", "Destination": "St Marie de Ré", "Destination State/Country": "France", "Difficulty Level": 4, "Geocode": "01010", "Influencers": ["recPGmcxQqIJxntNK"], "Magic Seaweed Link": "https://magicseaweed.com/Pipeline-Backdoor-Surf-Report/616/", "Peak Surf Season Begins": "2023-05-18", "Peak Surf Season Ends": "2023-08-31", "Photos": [[Object]], "Surf Break": ["Reef Break"]}, "id": "rec1Wf72NtCyMZzum"}
```

But when I have this error : [TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object]

I tried with FormData like this :

```
/*formData.append("fields['Destination']", location)
    formData.append("fields['Destination State/Country']", country)
    formData.append("fields['Difficulty Level']", Number(level))
    formData.append("fields['Surf Break']", surfBreak)
    formData.append("fields['Peak Surf Season Begins']", peakSurfSeasonBegins)
    formData.append("fields['Peak Surf Season Ends']", peakSurfSeasonEnds)
    formData.append("fields['Magic Seaweed Link']", "https://magicseaweed.com/Pipeline-Backdoor-Surf-Report/616/")
    formData.append("fields['Influencers']", influencers)
    formData.append("fields['Geocode']", geocode)*/

/*formData.append("fields['Photo']",{
                uri: imageUri,
                type: "image/jpeg",
                name: "image.jpeg"
            });*/
```

But nothing also.

Any helps is welcome !

Best Regards.